# Error: object.__new__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting the following message,  *this use to work before*. I have removed the .delay function below just to generate the message as this is a task but normally it looks like **ProcessRequests.delay.(batch)**

**object._*new*_() takes no parameters**

```
if request.method == 'POST':                               
    batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request.user) 
    for batch in batches:                                  
        ProcessRequests(batch)   #ProcessRequests.delay is normally used here                          
        batch.complete_update()
```

**Task:**

```
class ProcessRequests(Task):
    name = "Request to Process"
    max_retries = 1
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, batch):
        for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user, group=batch.group):
            msg = Message.objects.create(
                recipient_number=e.mobile,
                content=batch.content,
                sender=e.contact_owner,
                billee=batch.user,
                sender_name=batch.sender_name
            )
            gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=2)
            msg.send(gateway)
```

Full error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sms/process

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'south',
 'sms',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'async_messages.middleware.AsyncMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/s/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/s/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/s/sms/views.py" in process_all
  214.             ProcessRequests(batch)

Exception Type: TypeError at /sms/process
Exception Value: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to instantiate the `ProcessRequests` class with parameters, but that class doesn't have a constructor which takes parameters, hence the error.

I think you just need to change...

```
ProcessRequests(batch)
```

...to...

```
ProcessRequests().run(batch)
```

...but whether it will do what you want depends on the definition of the `Task` class.

Comment: it used to work like this and nothing has changed ProcessRequests.delay(batch)

Comment: So you changed `ProcessRequests.delay(batch)` to `ProcessRequests(batch)`, and yet you say that nothing has changed? That seems somewhat contradictory. Where is the `Task` class defined, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No its always been ProcessRequests.delay(batch), my code example I just changed to view the error. it does not work with ProcessRequests.delay(batch) anymore and now seems to work with ProcessRequests().delay(batch). @Aya solved the issue but whats changed is beyond me

Comment: The difference between ProcessRequests.delay(batch) and ProcessRequests().delay(batch) is the difference between classes and instances. In the former, you're calling the `delay()` method on the ProcessRequests *class*. In the latter, you're calling the method on an *instance* of the class.